# Specify type for an element that must have at least one child element

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

The element `elements` must contain at least the element `element1` or `element2`, but each of them at most once. For this I've specified the following XML Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
   <xs:element name="elements" type ="elementsType"/>
   <xs:complexType name="elementsType">
      <xs:choice>
         <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="element1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="element2" type="xs:double"/>
         </xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="element1" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:choice>
   </xs:complexType>
<xs:schema/>
```

Validation of this XML Schema gives a "Unique Particle Attribution" violation error:

> [cos-nonambig](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#cos-nonambig): element1 and element1 (or elements from their
>   substitution group) violate "Unique Particle Attribution". During
>   validation against this schema, ambiguity would be created for those
>   two particles.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your XSD violates the Unique Particle Attribution is due to the ambiguity across the `xs:choice` as to whether an `element1` should be associated with the first or second choice possibility.

You can avoid the violation and still require at least one of `element1` and `element2` using XSD 1.1's assertions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" elementFormDefault="qualified"
  vc:minVersion="1.1">
  <xs:element name="elements" type ="elementsType"/>
  <xs:complexType name="elementsType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="element1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="element2" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:assert test="count(*) > 0"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

---

### Update

> I don't understand why there is a ambiguity. If a instance contains
>   element1 and element2 or only element2 the first choice is only
>   possible. Otherwise, if there is only a element2, the second choice
>   applies only.

Pretend you're a validating parser and you encounter `element1`.  You won't know whether to associate it with the first or second branch of the `xs:choice`, thus the ambiguity.   Sure, you could look-ahead one level and resolve the ambiguity, but how far should you have to look-ahead?  The XSD recommendation says you as a validating parser shouldn't have to look-ahead at all in these circumstances.  Therefore, your job as an validator parser is easier (but your job as an XSD author is a bit harder).

Comment: I don't understand why there is a ambiguity. If a instance contains `element1` and `element2` or only `element2` the first choice is only possible. Otherwise, if there is only a `element2`, the second choice applies only.